# How to test Ionic Android application on macOS using Appium?

Tags: android, macos, selenium, appium, macos-sierra

I am trying to configure Appium for testing my Android application on macOS. Can someone provide steps for this configuration?

Previously I tested my Android application using Appium(Maven, Selenium Web Drivers, testNg) on Windows. For this I had dependencies in the environment variables (JAVA_HOME, MAVEN_HOME, ANDROID_HOME) set up on my Windows machine. How can I set these up for macOS?

Further to this, is it necessary to install an Android SDK on my mac?